# SavedStateHandle always give null when sharing ViewModel with JetpackCompose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am sharing the same ViewModel between **AppsScreen** and **HomeScreen** of Compose and passing data from **AppScreen** using **navigation** and want to receive in the **HomeViewModel** using **SaveStateHandle** but getting the null value always.

```
@Composable
fun ANNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String,
    route: String = HOME_ROUTE
) {
    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
        route = route
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Destinations.APPS
        ) { entry ->
            val backStackEntry = remember(entry) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry(HOME_ROUTE)
            }

            // Get the same instance every time
            val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(backStackEntry)

            AppsScreen(
                homeViewModel = homeViewModel,
                navController = navController
            )
        }

        composable(
            route = "${Destinations.HOME}/{$APP_ID_ARG}"
        ) { entry ->
            val backStackEntry = remember(entry) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry(HOME_ROUTE)
            }

            // Setting the appID in the savedStateHandle
            backStackEntry.savedStateHandle[APP_ID_ARG] = entry.arguments?.getString(APP_ID_ARG)

            // Get the same instance every time
            val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(backStackEntry)

            HomeScreen(
                homeViewModel = homeViewModel
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Don't know this will work or not but setting value to SaveStateHandle like this**

```
backStackEntry.savedStateHandle[APP_ID_ARG] = entry.arguments?.getString(APP_ID_ARG)
```

**Passing data using navigation**

```
navController.navigate("${Destinations.HOME}/$appID")
```

In ViewModel getting data like this

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val _savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
): ViewModel() {

    fun onEvent(event: HomeEvent) {

        when(event) {
            HomeEvent.OnAppsRefresh -> {
                getAppsID(refresh = true)
            }
            HomeEvent.OnHomePageRefresh -> {
                 val _appID =  _savedStateHandle.get<String>(DestinationsArgs.APP_ID_ARG)
                _appID?.let {
                    getData(appID = it, refresh = true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```